# Xamarin: Issues with handling OneSignal notifications when app is not in a background

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, background-process, onesignal

I have implemented the usage of OneSignal push notifications in Xamarin cross-platform application. I also save some metadata that is sent with the notification. It is done by `HandleNotificationReceived` method of my own `notificationService`

```
var notificationService = Mvx.Resolve<INotificationService>();
OneSignal.Current.StartInit(_oneSignalAppId).HandleNotificationReceived(notificationService.HandleNotificationReceived).EndInit();
```

The problem is that `HandleNoticationReceived` is touched only when application is not in foreground or background. But when application is not in a background, notifications are received, but `HandleNoticationReceived` is not touched, so no metadata is saved. It is the same for both Android and iOS versions. For iOS it doesn't even work when app is in background.
How can I make notifications work correctly when app is moved from background?